Typescript infer type of parameter without generic
I am creating a complex table configuration type, where I would like to infer the type of a value based on an accessor key.
The column configuration type looks like
type ColumnConfig<Row,Acc extends keyof Row = keyof row> = {
  accessor: Acc;
  render: React.FC<{value: Reducer<A, Row>}>;
}

The above works absolutely fine when both args are passed:
const foo: ColumnConfig<{foo: 'bar'}, 'bar'> = {
 accessor: 'bar',
 render: ({value}) => <></> // Value type hint is 'bar'
}

However, I don't always want to pass in the generic arg, as I would like to infer it.
const foo: ColumnConfig<{foo: 'bar'}> = {
 accessor: 'bar',
 render: ({value}) => <></> // Value type hint is keyof {foo: 'bar'}
}

It feels like typescript is refusing to infer the type whenever I pass any of the generic args. Is there a good way to get around this?
I have tried moving things around but I can't get away without passing the Row type here, else I lose type hinting in the accessor field.

Please [edit] your code so it's a [mre] without typos or name mismatches.  It's possible you're looking for this approach, but I had to change a bunch of things in your code to get this to work (especially {foo: 'bar'} and "bar"). Please fix the typos so that we can then move on to whether or not the distributive object type I've presented here works for your use case.

This is what you need, I guess
type ColumnConfig<Row,Acc extends keyof Row = keyof Row> = {
  accessor: Acc;
  render: React.FC<{value: Row[Acc]}>;
}

const foo: ColumnConfig<{foo: 'bar'}> = {
  accessor: 'foo',
  render: ({value}) => <></> // Value type hint is 'bar'
}


Perhaps, a mapped type should be fine for your case: TS Playground
It will let TypeScript infer the type of value directly from accessor
type ColumnConfig<Row> = {
  [K in keyof Row]: {
    accessor: K;
    render: (value: Row[K]) => void;
  };
}[keyof Row];


Unfortunately this doesn't quite fit my use case, as the K value here is actually passed through another utility, which I omitted to reduce the complexity.
The full type is currently:
type CellConfig<T extends Object, A extends NestedKeyOf<T> = NestedKeyOf<T>> = {
    accessor?: A;
    Render?: React.FC<{value: Reducer<Split<A, '.'>, T> }>;
}


